# CMS Made Simple Template creation

Tags: templates, content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

I have searched a lot the web for finding steps for creation Template for CMS made simple but not found anything related to this. How to create a template for CMS Made simple like we create templates in wordpress.

Comment: http://docs.cmsmadesimple.org/layout/create-your-own-template

Comment: but it doesn't say about where to put the template files and how to enable it..

Comment: I don't know much about this framework, but I honk you install templates from the admin/layout menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a useful video showing how to take a template and convert to CMSMS:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0g9WkCwO7s

In the CMSMS admin area you go to Layout -> Templates.  Then click Add new template.

To apply your template to all pages, go to Layout -> Templates.  Alongside your template click "Set All Pages".  Or you can apply to single pages by going to Content -> Pages, clicking the page you want, Options tab and change the Template drop down and click Submit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now i got a way to do this.